# How to use FluentValidation in Nancy project with StructureMapBootstrapper

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, nancy, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to test Nancy module, here's the calling code:

```
[Test]
public void Test_BadRequestIsSent_On_IssueWithNullTitle() {
    var browser = new Browser(with => with.Module(new IssuesModule()));
    var response = browser.Post("/api/issues/new", (with) => {
        with.HttpRequest();
        with.FormValue("Title", null);
    });
    Assert.Equals(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.StatusCode);
}
```

and I'm getting the exception:

> project.testing.fixtures.IssuesModuleFixtures.Test_BadRequestIsSent_On_IssueWithNullTitle:
>
> System.Exception : ConfigurableBootstrapper Exception ----> Nancy.RequestExecutionException : Oh noes!
>     ----> Nancy.Validation.ModelValidationException : **No model validator factory could be located**.
>
> Please ensure that you have an appropriate validation package installed, such as one of the Nancy.Validation packages.

Here's the DI configuration:

```
protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(StructureMap.IContainer container) {
    base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);

    container.Configure(config => {
        config.For<IModelValidatorFactory>().Use<FluentValidationValidatorFactory>().Singleton();
        config.For<IValidator<NewIssueViewModel>>().Use<NewIssueViewModelValidator>();

        config.Scan(scanner => {
            scanner.Assembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
            scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
    });
}
```

Validators are in the same assembly as `StructureMapBootstrapper` class.

What am I doing wrong? How do I setup **FluentValidation**?

Comment: You should install the  `Nancy.Validation.FluentValidation` package, I think it's enough. I'm using it but with autofac and I don't remember having to set anything with autofac